# Relation between strong profunctors and enriched profunctors

Tags: category-theory, enriched-category-theory

We know that in a closed monoidal category $V$, the two statements are equivalent:

1. $T$ is a strong endofunctor
2. $T$ is an (enriched) endofunctor in $V$ enriched over itself.

I'd like to know if there is a similar relationship between strong profunctors and enriched profunctors. I couldn't find the categorical definition of a strong profunctor, so I'm translating from Haskell: A strong profunctor is a functor from $C^{op}\otimes C$ to $Set$ with the following two natural transformations:
$$
T(a, b) \rightarrow T(c \otimes a, c \otimes b)
$$
$$
T(a, b) \rightarrow T(a \otimes c, a \otimes c)
$$
An enriched profunctor would be an (enriched) functor from $C^{op}\otimes C$ to $V$. (I'm mostly interested in $V$ being $Set$.)

Comment: That can't be the whole definition?

Comment: See definition 12 in [Arrows are Strong Monads](http://www-kb.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~asada/papers/arrStrMnd.pdf). There are some additional coherence conditions, but I think they are related to the profunctor being also a monad in $Prof$.